# Are modifications to a recipe needed to use frozen scallops instead of fresh?

Tags: seafood, frozen, scallops

I'm looking to try this recipe: http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2012/11/french-in-a-flash-broiled-scallops-provencale-recipe.html. I have frozen scallops, and though it doesn't specify, I suspect the recipe is for fresh scallops. Should I thaw the scallops ahead of time? Should I cook them at low temperature for awhile before broiling? If it makes a difference, these are the scallops I'm using: http://www.schwans.com/products/productDetail.aspx?id=52122&c1=10429

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the original recipe does not say explicitly that the scallops should be cooked from a frozen state, you should thaw them in the refrigerator before making the dish.  Do not precook them—just thaw them, and cook them as per the recipe.

You will also want to pat them dry with a paper towel or lint free towel, so that they are as dry as reasonably possible.